# setTimeout in jQuery .always() function fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tested this issue in firefox. I have the following jquery code:

```
function getSomething() {
    $.post(someUrl, {
        data: 'something'
    }, function (data) {
        // results in some data
    }, "json").always(function() {
        var timeR = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds
        var pingForSomething = setTimeout(function() {
            getSomething();
        }, timeR);
    });
}
```

This works fine. It posts to the url. And whether the post was successful or not, via `.always()`, it runs the function again after 10 seconds. However, I observed that in the long run (couple of minutes) this function is fired multiple times (Multiple times as in the function runs multiple times within 10 seconds, multiple instances of the function starts running simultaneously resulting in undesired frequent posts). Any idea why?

Comment: Since it *always* arranges for the timer to be set, and because the timer function *always* starts the process over, it keeps going. I don't understand what's confusing about that.

Comment: Because it's recursively doing the same: adding a timer event on itself ...

Comment: @Pointy multiple times, as in multiple times before 10 seconds

Comment: Suppose the request takes close to 10 seconds...

Comment: @AxelAmthor edited. multiple instances of the function starts running simultaneously resulting in very frequent posts.

Comment: Maybe the function is being called from different places. Add some `console.log()` calls to log when the function is being started from in the timer.